# Converting from JSON to Python objects||How to access this dictionary element

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import requests
import json
url='https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

Output looks like

```
{
    "kind": "books#volumes",
    "totalItems": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "books#volume",
            "id": "yZ1APgAACAAJ",
            "etag": "Wd66FTmnj2I",
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/yZ1APgAACAAJ",
            "volumeInfo": {
                "title": "Harry Potter 1 and the Philosopher's Stone",
                "authors": [
                    "J. K. Rowling"
                ],
```

Now that I want to access specific tags from this JSON

Example: value of "kind" key
value of "volumeInfo" key
value of "etag" key

Please help out in understanding how to access these dictionary

Comment: You access it like any other dictionary. What exactly was the problem?

Comment: After converting it to a dictionary that is... for that you can use the `json` module.

Comment: Hi could you put on some code that helps to pull values from the dictionary I have provided here.. u can consider key values fields that I have given under  example